# Configuring OpenLDAP init script on CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, openldap, init.d, startup-scripts, slapd

If I just run `slapd` with no arguments (as root) it starts and works fine. When I try to start it using `/etc/init.d/slapd start` however, it dies immediately.

I see from looking at the init script that there's a configuration file at `/etc/sysconfig/ldap`, but I haven't been able to find a working combination of settings. Does anybody know what I need to do?

---

I went back to the default init script and tried running with debugging, but I didn't see anything helpful. Main details were:

```
daemon --pidfile=/var/run/slapd.pid --check=slapd /usr/sbin/slapd -h '" ldap:///"' -u ldap
/bin/bash -c 'ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/sbin/slapd -h " ldap:///" -u ldap'`.
```

Comment: Any log file entries that would help?

Comment: @SvW Unfortunately no. All I know is that it creates the `.pid` file before it exits

Comment: I tried removing and hardcoding things in the init script until the `start()` function was just running `slapd` like I had done manually, and even then it doesn't work. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: which version of centos do you use?

Comment: you could try to run with some debug sh -x /etc/init.d/slapd start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to start manually using `/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap` and discovering it didn't work, I eventually thought to try turning off selinux (`setenforce 0`; I have [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/521126) about making it work with selinux enabled) which allowed it to run as the `ldap` user (and therefore allowed the standard init script to work).

The man page says that the default URL when `-h` is not given is `ldap:///` (TCP on all interfaces on default port). So to get the equivalent behavior to running slapd with no arguments you need to set

```
SLAPD_LDAP=yes
SLAPD_LDAPI=no
SLAPD_LDAPS=no
```

in `/etc/sysconfig/ldap`.