# Configure selinux to allow openldap on CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, openldap, selinux, slapd

I'm trying to run an OpenLDAP server on CentOS 6.4 with selinux enabled, but `slapd` is dieing as soon as it's started via `/etc/init.d/slapd start`. (init script reports OK; everything works fine after `setenforce 0`.

found these messages in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1372888328.397:3262): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=1492 comm="slapd" name="slapd.log" dev=dm-0 ino=4348 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1372888328.397:3262): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=1bd1018 a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=7ea191 items=0 ppid=1491 pid=1492 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts1 ses=337 comm="slapd" exe="/usr/sbin/slapd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1372888328.408:3263): avc:  denied  { sys_nice } for  pid=1492 comm="slapd" capability=23  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1372888328.408:3263): arch=40000003 syscall=156 success=yes exit=0 a0=5d4 a1=0 a2=bfe64968 a3=b787a6c0 items=0 ppid=1491 pid=1492 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts1 ses=337 comm="slapd" exe="/usr/sbin/slapd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1372888328.424:3264): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1493 comm="slapd" name="log.0000000001" dev=dm-0 ino=263969 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1372888328.424:3264): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no exit=-13 a0=1c78270 a1=8000 a2=0 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1493 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=337 comm="slapd" exe="/usr/sbin/slapd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

However this leaves me with no idea how to fix it. How do I tell selinux to allow the LDAP daemon to run?

---

I tried

```
restorecon -v -F -R /etc/openldap
restorecon -v -F -R /var/lib/ldap
```

but this didn't work (and in fact it seems to have broken my ability to start slapd *even with selinux disabled*). Got a lot of messages like

> restorecon reset /etc/openldap/cacerts context unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0->system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0

Comment: I have a feeling that your ldap database is stored in a place other than /var/lib/ldap (which is labelled properly). As for the niceness -- I cant find any documentation suggesting slapd can actually change its niceness, if it can, its a bug in policy to not allow it.

Answer (score 3):

If you filter the audit logs through `audit2allow(1)` and `audit2why` you'll get an approximate idea of what is happening:

```
#============= slapd_t ==============
allow slapd_t self:capability sys_nice;
allow slapd_t var_log_t:file { write read };
------------------------------------

    Was caused by:
            Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

            You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

type=AVC msg=audit(1372888328.408:3263): avc:  denied  { sys_nice } for  pid=1492 comm=slapd capability=23  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 tclass=capability

    Was caused by:
            Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

            You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

type=AVC msg=audit(1372888328.424:3264): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1493 comm=slapd name=log.0000000001 dev=dm-0 ino=263969 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:slapd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file

    Was caused by:
            Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

            You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

### Checking labeling

It is unlikely a label restore prevents you from starting a service **if SELinux is in permissive mode**. Also, why the `-F` switch?

To know if you have to restore the labeling of a directory or file, first find out what context a file or directory is supposed to have:

```
# matchpathcon /etc/openldap/
/etc/openldap   system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
```

Then list its security context:

```
# ls -ldZ /etc/openldap/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       /etc/openldap//
```

In this example, no further action is needed.

With regards to your issue, the problem is not labeling *per se*, but a missing `type enforcement` rule, i.e., a rule that allows a labeled process to *transition* from one confined domain to another, or to read files with an specific label, for example.

### Creating an SELinux module

You can try to build a module that allows the `slapd_t` to perform the operations which appeared in the `audit.log`. It is probable that you need further adjustments in your code. Use `audit2allow`, and `make` for this task. All commands are very well documented in their respective manpages. The process will look roughly like this (after copying the relevant messages into `audit.txt`):

```
audit2allow -i audit.txt -m slapd -o slapd.te
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile load
```

Also, check if a bug report for the SELinux policy regarding this issue already exists.

Comment: I used `-F` because that's what was done in another thread I found. Seems to have changed the owner of some files, which caused the init script to fail. `chmod -R ldap:ldap /var/lib/ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d` fixed that part of the problem.

Comment: I agree, this looks like a bug, and should be reported as such.

Comment: @MichaelHampton where would the correct place to report this be? CentOS, Redhat, or somewhere else?

Comment: I think you can report on CentOS bugzilla. After investigation they will inform you